# How are classes implemented in compilers

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design, llvm

I'd like to implement a class type for my own little language but what I thought at first wouldn't be too hard has got me stumped. I have the parser in place and it's the code generation side of things I'm having problems with. Can anyone shed any light on the best/correct way to go about this? Specifically I'd like to do this in LLVM so while I need to know the generalities of this any specific LLVM code I should be working with would be fantastic.

Thanks T.

---

N.B. The experience I have with LLVM is basically what comes from the Kaleidoscope tutorials and a little extra from playing around with it but I am far from having a full understanding of the LLVM API's.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer the question. What is it you want to accomplish with LLVM? (BTW I know very little about LLVM and probably won't be the answerer.)

Comment: @Qwertie. The ultimate goal is to implement a compiler for my own little language and right now I'm trying to implement C++-style classes. So any information on how to go about this would be nice, but I think maybe I need to understand the LLVM API better first so, as I say, any thoughts on where to go/what to do to continue learning after completing the Kaleidoscope tutorials would be a help too.

Comment: @tjm: This question is quite vague. Do you already have an idea of how you'd implement classes in general and you only need help how to implement it with LLVM? Or do you want to know how classes can be implemented in general?

Comment: @sepp2k. Thanks for your comment. I need advice on how to do this in general but I am specifically looking to do it in LLVM. I have some ideas of how it may be done but don't know (doubt) they are the ideal/usual ways of going about it. I've rewritten the question but I am not sure whether I've made it worse or better! Any thoughts? I may delete it and try again later but thought I'd try a rewrite first.

Comment: Furthermore, do you want to know how a compiler may represent classes and class hierachies internally, or how the LLVM IR can be generated?

Comment: Thanks @delnan. How the IR is generated mostly.

Comment: This question isn't clear, what type of class are we talking about? (It could be HASKELL CLASSES!)

Answer (score 6):

A very, very incomplete overview:

**Class** is a structure (you know C/C++ don't you?)

**Methods** are otherwise ordinary functions except they receive an extra implicit argument: the object itself. This argument is usually called 'this' or 'self' within the function. Class-scope symbols may (C++, JavaScript) or may not (PHP, Python) be accessible by default within methods.

**Inheritance** is essentially gluing together the structures and possibly also merging symbol tables as well, as normally symbols of the base class are accessible by default from within the methods of a class you are now parsing. When you encounter a symbol (field or method) within a method you need to do an ascending lookup, starting from the current class going up the hierarchy. Or you may implement it so that you look it up only in one symbol table which is a result of a merger.

**Virtual methods** are called indirectly. In some languages all methods are virtual by default. The implementation would depend on whether it's a fully dynamic language, in which case you always look up a function name within a class *at run-time* and thus all your methods become virtual automatically; or in case of static languages compilers usually build so called virtual method tables. I'm not sure if you need this at all, so I won't go into details here.

**Constructors** are special methods that are called either when constructing a new object (usually with 'new') or otherwise are called as part of the constructor call chain from within descendant constructors. Many different implementations are possible here, one being that a constructor takes an implicit 'this' argument, which may be NULL if an object hasn't been created yet, and returns it as well.

**Destructiors** are ordinary methods that are normally called implicitly when an object goes out of scope. Again you need to take into account a possibility of an ascending call chain for destructors.

**Interfaces** are tricky unless, again, your language is fully dynamic.

Comment: +1 Nice summary, I generally agree. Except that interfaces are not any harder than inheritance in general.

Comment: @delnan thanks. In general, in static languages interfaces are trickier than ordinary virtual calls: for each interface method call an extra step is involved to find the VMT of that particular interface. A caller may or may not know the exact type of an object through which this call is performed. But as I said in dynamic languages you basically do nothing except maybe some run-time compatibility checks.

Comment: As the famous quote states, "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" ;) Of course it takes an additional step, but it's not really complicated.

Comment: @delnan: right :) Of course complication here is, rather, in making an Intf. method call as efficient as possible. A few implementations in static languages that I've seen used linear search to find an Intf. VMT by an internal ID. And that's for each call! I don't know if better implementations exist to be honest.

Comment: I suppose since the VMT won't change after compilation, a balanced binary tree might be possible. Also, polymorphic inline cache could do wonders here. But anyway: First make the prototype compiler work correctly, *then* wonder about the best implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You should buy Stan Lippmann, *Inside The C++ Object Model.* Everything you need is in there.

Comment: Do you mean Lippman, Inside the C++ Object Model? I can't find anything by a Lipschitz with a similar name. If not, I apologise for my ignorance.

Comment: Thanks, I see a visit to the library in my near future.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several strategies to realize this, here is one:

A **vtable** (Virtual Table) is a compile-time-constant struct with function pointers. (All values are known at compile-time.)

(You can call the pointer to a vtable an "interface", if you want.)

An OOP-class in a language without any ability of inheritance is a struct that contains a const pointer to its vtable as first member-variable.
This pointer is used to exactly identify the type of the object, and with multi-inheritance the aspect/view (as what casted?) on that object.

If you want to have multi-inheritance, then you need to be able to (static_)cast the pointer to a derived class to its parent class, correcting the byte-address on the fly. This could be realized with one virtual function or (better) with a signed offset value stored in the vtable.

A (dynamic_)cast from the pointer to a parent class to the pointer to a derived class either implies a lookup in a probably large datastructure (array,hashtable,whatever) or is realized via one virtual function, too.

Each call to a function from the vtable needs the object-pointer to be casted to the type, that is appropriate for the function. This might be done either by the caller, reading the signed offset (correspoinding to the function) from the vtable, or by the callee, which then is only a proxy of the original function.

In some languages (especially functional languages) you can define references to (untyped) objects that instanciate a list of interfaces/typeclasses, valid on that object. Such a reference contains one pointer to the base-object and a list of pointers to the relevant vtables.